# XML File Parsing and fetching the tags?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, xml.etree

xml =

```
<company>Mcd</company>        
<Author>Dr.D</Author>
```

I want to fetch Mcd and Dr.D.
My try

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
e = et.parse(xml)
root = e.getroot()
for node in root.getiterator("company"):
   print node.tag
```

Hopping for a generous help.

Comment: Hey got my answer :)    
    using `xml.dom.minidom import parseString

Comment: `xml.dom.minidom` is not a recommended course unless you already know the DOM API intimately. The documentation rightly recommends you use `ElementTree` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply find the *one* tag that matches, then take the `.text` attribute:

```
company = root.find('.//company').text
author = root.find('.//Author').text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
    xmlFile = ET.iterparse(open('some_file.xml','r'))

    for tag, value in xmlFile:
        print value.text
```